# Using a function to make a list

Tags: python, list

for some time now I have been creating these list with similar labels such as "March_01_2017","March_02_2017" and so on, these list are basically dated sequences.

Instead of having to repeatedly type a list display like:

```
>>>Date=[]
```

I would rather pass a parameter to a function and have it do the job for me. my problem right now is that I don't know how to get a function to do this task, or know what I need to read to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dictionary?

```py
import datetime

dict_of_lists = {}
def add_list():
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B_%d_%Y")
    if date not in dict_of_lists:
        dict_of_lists[date] = []
    else:
        print("Key already exists")
```

Now you can call `add_list()` once everyday to create a new list with the required label.

*Sample Output*:

```
In [51]: dict_of_lists
Out[51]: {}

In [52]: add_list()

In [53]: dict_of_lists
Out[53]: {'March_02_2018': []}

In [54]: add_list()
Key already exists
```